# update an attribute value using wildcards

Tags: ant

I would have thought that if you didn't provide a destination, xmltask would modify the source file and replace it, but apparently that's not the case since the below code does not work:

```
<xmltask source="**\plugin.xml"> 
    <attr path="plugin" attr="version" value="12345" /> 
</xmltask>
```

If I specify a destination, I get an error saying "Multiple inputs, but only one destination":

```
<xmltask source="**\plugin.xml" dest="**\plugin.xml"> 
    <attr path="plugin" attr="version" value="12345" /> 
</xmltask>
```

How can I get this to work with wildcards? Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of specifying a single output file with `dest`, specify an output directory with `todir`:

```
<xmltask source="**\plugin.xml" todir="output"> 
   <attr path="plugin" attr="version" value="12345" /> 
</xmltask>
```